# Tips on avoiding "Could not activate cellular data network" with New iPad

Tags: ipad, cellular-data

So I bought a new iPad, 64GB + 4G. And since then it seems like every time I pick it up and go to use a network feature (Hero Academy, Tweetbot, Safari etc.) I get this message "Could not activate cellular data network".

If I reset it then everything will work OK until after I put it away for a while. There's no definite time period for the network failing but it always seems to happen after I have been home or at work (inside a WiFi coverage area) and then I go to use 3G again. The fact that it does work fine after a reset says to me that this is not a signal strength issue, this happens repeatedly at the train station and will always work right after reset. Before reset the network indicator shows full bars and 3G indicator.

Has anyone else experienced this and improved this by changing anything in Settings, by talking to their carrier or anything else? I am thinking this has to be an iOS bug. I should not have to do a white apple reset to use network services!

If it matters I am using a prepaid Optus 3G sim in Melbourne, Australia. My only APN setting is the APN field which is "connectme", correct according to the Optus guide I got with my sim. (new iPad cannot use the 4G networks available in Australia: [Australian Competition & Consumer Commission](http://www.accc.gov.au/content/index.phtml/itemId/1042020/fromItemId/142))

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. My iPad is wifi + 4G 16GB. Everything that was written on top could have been written by me. I use the network TMN in Portugal, and the only difference is that I'm in a contract, and not in a prepaid.

Comment: How do you reset the iPad?

Comment: Hold top and home buttons until white apple appears. Don't know who is down voting you, not me!

Comment: In that case, see my edit :)

Comment: I also had this on T-Mobile UK (3G and HSDPA only, not LTE, network shared with Orange UK), so I don't think it's an operator specific issue.  The fix (so far) was mark's suggestion below: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/48931/12164

Comment: Since the 5.1.1 update this has not occurred again although I have been trying to make it happen, to gather data for the radar issue I filed.

Answer (score 4):

I have had exactly the same issues with my New Ipad 16Gb 4G.
The only way I have found that really gets round it, is to manually select the Network provider, insteady of leaving it set to the 'Automatic' setting.
Come on Optus sort this out !!

Comment: This worked for me - having similar problem with the new iPad (iPad 3) on T-Mobile UK.   I also tried rebooting, checking APN settings, but this is the only thing that worked.  Recommend people try this as it's not at all disruptive compared to rebooting, resetting network settings, etc.

Comment: You are great! I spent hours doing complicated things when it was this simple!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the website of Optus](http://optus.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/47/kw/APN/session/L3RpbWUvMTMzMzYxMDg2NS9zaWQveXJodGFTVWs=#iPhone/BlackBerry), all should be working after a sync with iTunes (this is about an iPhone, but I'm sure it applicable to an iPad as well):

> **iPhone**
>   iPhone specific APNs and technical settings are automatically
>   provisioned when you first connect your iPhone (with an Optus SIM card
>   inserted) to iTunes and activate your service. Performing a restore
>   will also resend these settings to your iPhone.

**UPDATE:**
Try to reset your network settings by going to *Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings*

[image]

Comment: If you cast a negative vote, please leave a comment so I can improve my answer where you think it's needed...

Comment: I would have thought I had any required setting but could try it again I suppose. I did sync to restore my old iPad's backup data to the new one.

Comment: Thanks - tried it but no luck.  Still complains that "couldn't activate the cellular network".